# Used git reset --hard "commit id", and now my HEAD is detached

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-branch

I am rather new to git.

**The Problem:** Just wanted to merge my remote main branch with a merge branch.

I wanted to sync my remote main branch with a merge branch I was working on: The merge branch was 80 commits behind the main. For some reason, I encountered some conflicts, and the auto merge failed.

I then tried switching to my remote main branch *(git checkout origin/main)*, and it failed too, suggesting I resolve the conflicts first. I decided to simply go back to an earlier commit, for which I used:

`git reset --hard *commit id*`

I then deleted my merge branch, and proceeded to create a new merge branch off of remote main branch (origin/main). This is where the problem begins. I write

`git checkout origin/main`

and am presented with this

```
Note: switching to 'origin/main'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental 
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.      

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may 
do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:       

  git switch -c <new-branch-name>

Or undo this operation with:

  git switch -

Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false

HEAD is now at *commit id* *Description*
```

I did all that I could, read articles, read stackoverflow questions, even deleted and cloned my local repository but somehow couldn't manage to **re-attach** the HEAD to the remote branch, if you may.

Is there anything that I'm missing here? All I want is to use git checkout origin/main and it should point to the branch instead of the specific commit id.

Any and all help is appreciated. Banging my head to fix this since the last 5 hours.

Comment: You can't check out remote branches, you can only check out the commit they reference. This is why you ended up in a detached head state. You didn't check out `origin/main`, you checked out the commit it referenced. Instead, check out your *local* `main` branch that is linked to the remote branch and then move that around according to your needs. Then later do a "force push" to forcibly update the remote branch to match. **NOTE!** Be **absolutely** sure you know what you're doing here or you risk removing commits from the remote that you don't want to remove!

Comment: So from my understanding, moving forward, if I have to push a change I should so forcefully? Or should I just try the regular `git push` and it'll work? 
And will that make my HEAD point back to the branch instead of the commit?

Comment: You said you read articles, SO, and so on. Did git's advice not work `git switch -c <new-branch-name>`.  If so, what is the error.

Comment: I now understand your comment. The concept of detached HEAD was confusing at first, thanks for  clearing it out. 
@RenéLink There is no error. git checkout origin/main pointed to the commit it referenced and not the branch per say which I believed was an "error", while it was just a normal state. 
Thank you all for clarifying!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I then deleted my merge branch, and proceeded to create a new **merge** branch off of remote main branch (origin/main)

That's actually not what you did. `git checkout origin/main` checked out the commit referenced by `origin/main` and therefore ended up in detached head state.

What you needed to do was `git checkout -b merge origin/main`. This would have effectively created the local `merge` branch starting at `origin/main` and checked it out.

If you are currently in detached head state you should be able to just execute the above-mentioned command to fix your problem.

Comment: Ah. I now see. 
I've been using the UI in VS Code for creating new branches. While doing that, I couldn't locate origin/main in the dropdown which is why I wrote `git checkout origin/main` just to confirm if I can perhaps find it via the terminal. 
It makes much more sense now. 
I'll give this command _git checkout -b merge origin/main_ a shot while working on the next merge, and hopefully it should work!

Thank you for clarifying the situation! :D

Comment: @RishabhMaini If this answer answered your question, please consider clicking the accept button beneath the voting number.